# LINQ - how to remove duplicate rows in table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

After certain proccess, I wan to remove duplicates from the table and commit the changes, so only single values remain.

I have three criteria for removal:

- Name
- date
- status (is always 1)

So if there are records with same Name, and same date and same status... remove one. Does not matter which one.

I have:
dbContext.tbl_mytable

Comment: So you are using `Linq To SQL`, right? Does the table have primary keys?

Comment: Yes. I use Linq to SQL. Table has primary keys.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you are talking about **deleting** records, you need to **test** this first.

> So if there are records with same Name, and same date and same status... remove one. Does not matter which one.

I'm assuming you want to remove all but one, ie, if you have three records with the same details, you remove two and leave one.

If so, you should be able to identify the duplicates by grouping by { Name, date, status} and then selecting all except the first record in each group.

ie something like

```
var duplicates = (from r in dbContext.tbl_mytable 
                  group r by new { r.Name, r.date, r.status} into results
                  select results.Skip(1)
                 ).SelectMany(a=>a);

 dbContext.tbl_mytable.DeleteAllOnSubmit(duplicates);
 dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```